# Mesh won't bevel (2nd time)

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I have two objects (from a Collada import), one can be beveled, the other not. I cannot see any differences in the mesh. I checked for non-manifold edges, I checked for the orientation of the normals, I checked for sharp edges, ... What am I missing?

[image: Blender screenshot]

The .blend file (version 2.81) can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAP6OKinOxeC5PAGGCIZJp6WsqX2sHdYds-C1aVJGl63GLkFIH_g

Thanks in advance for any help!

Chris

Answer (score 2):

There are many duplicate vertices.

In edit mode, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), then *Right click > Merge > By distance*.

Comment: That's it! And it was quick! Why does the "problematic" mesh now looks nicer than the other one?

Comment: First, one has some faces set as smooth. To even things off, do *Object > Shade smooth* on both objects. They will still look different, though, because for some reason the vertex normals are at 90 degrees with the "other" and at 45 degrees with the "problematic"

Comment: Using "Harden normals" in the bevel modifier options of the "Other" one, in addition to "Shade smooth" on both as stated above, will make them look the same.

Comment: @ChrisS. Please don't add thank you as an answer, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted